# UnknownError when attempting to list existing synchronization jobs for a given servicePrincipals ID

Tags: synchronization, provisioning

I'm receiving the following error while hitting the [list existing synchronization jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationjob-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) endpoint with a servicePrincipals ID for one of my enterprise applications.

```
{
    "error" : 
    {
        "code" : "UnknownError",
        "innerError" : 
        {
            "client-request-id" : "{id}",
            "date" : "2021-01-22T14:33:26",
            "request-id" : "{id}"
        },
        "message" : ""
    }
}
```

So far, I've verified the servicePrincipals ID is correct in a couple different ways. I was able to use this endpoint successfully to obtain that:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$select=id,appId,displayName&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'dropbox')
```

Details of my request:

```
URL:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{id}/synchronization/jobs/

Headers:
-X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}"

Request body: (None)
```

[image: Screenshot of permissions granted to my app]
Any insights into why I am getting an error?

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out? I am stuck on this... Are you using "Application" or "Delegated" permissions? It seems for the Application permission we also need the permission Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationjob-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions)